# Async/await promise function to dynamically set timeout ms

Tags: javascript

I am tring to set timeout ms dynamically whenenver a dom if fully rendered ,  currently it is set 1000ms , however rendering time will vary from time to time. is there possibilty that we could use render time to dynamically set timeout in mockcall function ? or should i make changes on updateDOM variable .

```js
function mockCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
  })
}

async function makeMockCall() {
  await mockCall();
  let end = window.performance.now();
  let time = end - start;
}

let updateDOM = makeMockCall().then(render => {
  setTimeout(customStyle(input), render)
});

console.log(updateDOM);
```

Comment: `function mockCall(delay) {
          return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          setTimeout(()=> resolve(), delay);
        })
      }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know when DOM loaded so you can use event DOMContentLoaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
// your code
});
```